# Problem with draw bitmap on rotated canvas around X axis

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

Good day,

I have weird problem with drawing image. Code and pictures say more then words.

```
mCamera.save();
mCamera.rotateX(rotateX);
mCamera.getMatrix(mMatrix);
mCamera.restore();

canvas.save();
canvas.setMatrix(mMatrix);

// here I draw images
...

canvas.restore();
```

and results are at images below. First picture have angle 0, second around 45 degree and last something more. It depend on size of area (number of bitmaps) I want to draw. I notice that when I draw bitmaps that whole fits canvas bounds, it works fine. But problem is mainly when I draw images with something like (so with part outside of canvas)

```
canvas.drawBitmap(image, -100, -100, null)
```

and images (hmm, because I'm new here, I cannot post images directly ...)

ttp://locus.asamm.cz/data/_temp/1311873666794.png

http://locus.asamm.cz/data/_temp/1311873695945.png

http://locus.asamm.cz/data/_temp/1311873782054.png

So question is, if there is any working solution or at least any tip. Also if anyone experienced can tell if drawing with OpenGL can help with this and if so, please point me to any information source that can help me with drawing bitmaps that change a lot (it's map application so user move with map), because I still cannot find any simple and clear source of info.

Thanks to all very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a limitation of the 2D drawing API. To do true 3D you should use OpenGL.

Comment: hmm I was worried that I'll receive this answer. So also second question. Any tip for sample solution that should help me better understand way how to display dynamically loaded bitmaps in OpenGL? I know there is a lot of tutorials, but every show only how to display already preloaded bitmaps or some vectors. Thanks

Comment: Have to accept this answer after more then year another active developing. Seems that common "canvas" ways isn't enough powerful for this task and using OpenGL is the only solution. Thanks both for help

Answer (score 0):

I expect you are trying to produce a google maps tilt/rotate effect which I have successfull done for google maps since they don't think we need an update ;-) and I needed it for my application, even if you are using your own tiles it's basically the same thing.

One thing that helps is realize that the rotations for the Camera Matrix are performed in the upper left corner.

So you should transform to the appropriate location (dependent on axis of rotation and your expected results) and then back, something like ... the effects you are getting were very similar to mine before I read the docs and figured that out.

```
camera.save();
    camera.rotateX(tilt);  // tilt forward or backward
    camera.rotateY(0);
    camera.rotateZ(angle); // Rotate around Z access (similar to canvas.rotate)                                 

     camera.getMatrix(cameraMatrix);

     // This moves the center of the view into the upper left corner (0,0) 
     // which is necessary because Matrix always uses 0,0, as it's transform point
     // use the center of the canvas, or the bottom center dependent on your results 
     cameraMatrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);

     // NOTE: Camera Rotations logically happen here when the canvas has the matrix applied  
     // This happens after the camera rotations are applied, moving the view back to 
     // where it belongs, allowing us to rotate around the center or any point we choose 

     // Move it back after the rotations are applied
     cameraMatrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);

camera.restore();

canvas.concat(cameraMatrix);
```

The other thing to do is to oversize the container so you don't have empty space (or at least limit it) after your tilt/rotate operations, you can do that by calculating the needed oversize, the diagonal of your display works for basic rotation, + a percentage based on tilt if you are using that.

Playing around with the pre/postTranslate can can give you some interesting results.

As to moving the bitmap I am not really sure why you are doing this, probably panning, but as long as the canvas is getting filled it shouldn't matter

**Update**

Here is how I oversize the canvas, I tried to use the LayoutParams to do this but didn't have much luck with it so on Measure was the way to go for me.

```
@Override 
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    if (!isInEditMode())
        super.onMeasure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(scaledDimensionsW,
        View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(scaledDimensionsH,
        View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
   else
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response. By your code I can see that I'm doing everything is same way (or almost same). As you can see on attached images in my first post, I'm rotating canvas in correct way (around center). Also oversizing is done. For example when screen is 800x480, I set area for map draw to 2000x2000 and I apply valid translation to matrix to place map on correct place. Even with this, image is very similar ... invalid lines over display. As Romain menioned, I'll have to use some OpenGL method, but after half day of searching, I still have no idea how to simply change canvas to OpenGL

Comment: Well it's working ok for me, I am having no real issues with this, I am limiting the tilt to 45 degree's since I dont need more but I have gone up to 60 as a test and still no problems. How are you oversizing the canvas? And you are doing pre-post translation as well?

Comment: hmm damn ... yes I'm using exactly same mechanism. But in place you use preTranslate by centerX, Y, I use preTranslate for custom defined size. And this size also define area on which are tiles drawn. Hmm, but looks it have to work in some way. May you please tell is you directly change size of canvas (if this is possible)? Because me not. I just "say to my map", canvas size is 2000x2000 (even it's only 480x800) and I just draw on "this" (area 2000x2000). So I preTranslate(-1000, -1000) and postTranslate(240, 400). When I rotate only around Z, it works perfectly. Around X cause troubles.

Comment: hmm very interesting!! Have to try and I'll let you know. Thank you!!

Comment: Idistic, I have no success with your solution. Exactly same problem. I created sample and very simple application (http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8015949/Locus%20%28dev%29/RotateTest.zip) that only thanks to SeekBar, rotate some rectangles with my method, and there you can simply see what's wrong. So if you have a little time, look on it. Maybe you'll see what I do wrong. And also think, how can I repay to you for your time :). Thank you

Comment: I will try and take a look later today, since I am using the Google MAP API and I don't handle panning etc. it may have something to do with order of operations.

Comment: Hi Idistic, did you find some time to look at it, if you have idea where should be problem? Anyway thank you for your time!

Comment: Hi @Idistic, more quesitons on your impl: I've been using an angle of 35.264 (iso), but do you know what the angle google is using on their perspective view is?